# Error Calling DescribeIndexFieldsAsync on AmazonCloudSearchClient

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I've confirmed that I have permissions to perform the request.

According to amazon's [Cloud Search Dev Troubleshooting Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-search-doc-access-policies) the error I'm experiencing is likely due to the .net sdk using the wrong api version.  I don't see a way to specify the api version explicitely.

I want to avoid having to manually create the http request.

I want to make the request through the SDK.

I've tried all the available versions of the SDK and all of them give me this error.

I've also tried specifying the request properties in various combinations.  Nothing works.

Can anybody give me direction as to how I can resolve this issue?

Expected behavior: return info for all index fields

Actual behavior:

error - 
"Result Message:
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonUnmarshallingException : Error unmarshalling response back from AWS. Response Body: {
  "message": "Request forbidden by administrative rules",
  "__type": "CloudSearchException"
}"

----> System.Xml.XmlException : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Code sample:

```
var _configClient = new AmazonCloudSearchClient(
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudSearchAccessKey"],
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudSearchSecretKey"],
                    new AmazonCloudSearchConfig
                    {
                        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2,
                        ServiceURL = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudSearchUrl"]
                    });

await _configClient.DescribeIndexFieldsAsync(new DescribeIndexFieldsRequest())
```

Answer (score 0):

CloudSearch is returning json, which you can see in your response body, and the SDK is trying to unmarshal that into xml. When you make a query directly, you can add `&format=xml` to get xml results. There should be an analogous option in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't see any such option for the .Net SDK.  Either in the constructor params or the method params.